# How to sync TFS with GitHub after cloning to Git?

Tags: git, github, tfs

I'm doing a trial run of migrating from TFS to Git (hosting on GitHub).  I used Git-TFS to clone the repository several weeks ago, and that took about half a day to run.  Now developers have been checking in more code on TFS and I want to pull all those checkins across to GitHub.

What's the command to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have been putting all the `TFS` changes into the `master` branch, the following should work:

```
git checkout master
git tfs pull
```

This will pull all changes in from `TFS`.  Then you can push `master` to GitHub:

```
git push origin master
```